# Compare two columns in same table

Tags: mysql

Guys how can I make this query work

```
SELECT SUM(iznos_fakture) as ukupno 
FROM fakture_placanja 
WHERE iznos_placanja <> iznos_fakture 
AND MONTH(datum_dospijeca) = '12'
```

I need to find where iznos_placanja (decimal 10,2) is different from iznos_fakture (Decimal 10,2). They are two columns in same table?

I want to find all invoices (iznos_fakture) which are due in December (MONTH(datum_dospijeca)) and have not been payed yet (iznos_placanja).

Nulls are allowed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Database are you using? Could you add the appropriate tag to your question?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6.17

Answer (score 0):

How about using the sum inside your WHERE clause?

```
SELECT SUM(iznos_fakture) 
FROM fakture_placanja WHERE 
iznos_placanja <> iznos_fakture 
AND MONTH(datum_dospijeca) = '12'
```

Comment: It's not working. For some reason WHERE clause is not working. Even in a simple query like this, there is no result. SELECT iznos_fakture 
  FROM fakture_placanja 
  WHERE iznos_placanja != iznos_fakture

Comment: as asked above, which DBMS are you using? In most cases you would use `<>` rather than `!=` as comparison operators.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6.17. I have tried != and <> but no result is returned. Don't know why. Is it OK to do this in WHERE clause [column_name] <> [column_name]?

Comment: Any errors shown when you run the query in MySQL Query Browser or HeidiSQL? How are the column types of `iznos_placanja` and `iznos_fakture`?

Comment: No errors. I tried in dbForge. Both columns are DECIMAL(10,2).

Comment: What is the result of the inner statement `SELECT SUM(iznos_fakture) as ukupno 
  FROM fakture_placanja 
  WHERE iznos_placanja != iznos_fakture 
  AND MONTH(datum_dospijeca) = '12'`?

Comment: Now we are getting closer. It seems as if the values of iznos_placanja and iznos_fakture are always the same, at least for month december. I removed the inner column compare from my query above, could you edit your own question and add some more information regarding what the columns contain and what you want to achieve with your query?

Comment: There is my problem. I see that there is two invoices (iznos_fakture) which are due in December. They have not been payed yet (that's column iznos_placanja) and I want to display to user that this month he will have two invoices with amount of XXX to pay. For some reason the result is not returned. Even if I take away AND MONTH(datum_dospijeca) = '12' it's not returning any result. So I guess there's something wrong in comparing iznos_placanja <> iznos_fakture.

Comment: OK, it seems I found my problem. I have checked nulls allowed and that is problem. I have put 0 to all records and now is working.

Comment: I just wanted to invite you to a chat room because I expected the problem to be more complex than a simple column comparison not working :-) Good to hear you solved it!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help a bit with your research :-) Could you mark your question as self-answered, just add an answer to your question with a short explanation as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved)